# how can I get more specific font information use poi XWPF API? when I use one Calibri font file to test, the fontName I get is null and fontsize is -1

Tags: java, fonts, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I use this code to test one Times New Roman font file and one Calibri font file. As for Times New Roman, the code can return the font name but not font size. As for Calibri, I can't get either font name or font size. I don't know what's wrong happened...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("F:\\workspace\\zExtractInformationTest2\\bold.docx");
        XWPFDocument document;
        try {
            document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));
            List<XWPFParagraph> paraList = document.getParagraphs();

            for (int index = 0; index < paraList.size(); index++) {
                XWPFParagraph para = paraList.get(index);
                for (XWPFRun run : para.getRuns()) {
                    String font = run.getFontName();
                    int fontSize = run.getFontSize();
                    String text = run.text();
                    boolean isBold = run.isBold();
                    System.out.println("run:        "+font+"\t"+fontSize+"\t"+text+"\t"+isBold);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Word]

Comment: When I use default font size in the Chinese format, the code cannot extract the font size information and return -1. When I set the word document font size to a digital format, the code can get the correct font size.

When I use any other fonts, I can really get the font information. But no matter how I set the font to Calibri, the code always return null as a font extract result.

This may specify what I had said above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default font size & default font problem. Use the method follow can get default layout xml text directly, and then you can know the default font size, default font, and default alignment.

```
private String[] getDefault() {
    String[] defaultAttibts = new String[] { "", "", "" };
    try {
        CTStyles styles = document.getStyle();
        if (styles.isSetDocDefaults()) {
            String docDefaults = styles.getDocDefaults().xmlText();
            if (docDefaults.contains("jc")) {
                docDefaults = docDefaults.substring(docDefaults.indexOf("jc"));
                docDefaults = docDefaults.substring(docDefaults.indexOf("=\"") + 2);
                defaultAttibts[0] = docDefaults.substring(0, docDefaults.indexOf("\"")).toUpperCase();
            }
            if (docDefaults.contains("sz")) {
                docDefaults = docDefaults.substring(docDefaults.indexOf("sz"));
                docDefaults = docDefaults.substring(docDefaults.indexOf("=\"") + 2);
                defaultAttibts[1] = docDefaults.substring(0, docDefaults.indexOf("\""));
            }
            if (docDefaults.contains("rFonts")) {
                docDefaults = docDefaults.substring(docDefaults.indexOf("rFonts"));
                docDefaults = docDefaults.substring(docDefaults.indexOf("=\"") + 2);
                defaultAttibts[2] = docDefaults.substring(0, docDefaults.indexOf("\""));
            }
        }
        CTStyle[] style = styles.getStyleArray();
        for (CTStyle s : style) {
            if (s.isSetDefault() && s.isSetType()) {
                if (s.getType().toString().equals("paragraph") && s.getDefault().toString().equals("1")) {
                    String text = s.xmlText();
                    if (defaultAttibts[1] == "") {
                        text = text.substring(text.indexOf("sz"));
                        text = text.substring(text.indexOf("=\"") + 2);
                        defaultAttibts[1] = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("\""));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (XmlException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return defaultAttibts;
}
```

Comment: you can change the postfix into .zip, open the zipped document and find styles.xml. The xml text you get from this method is an excerpt from that file.